# jQuery.Deferred in recursive cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, recursion, jquery-deferred

I have a complex problem with asyncronious functions in my code.
I have an object and I have to apply different functions (animations, content analysis, etc) to it.

```
this.buildChain = function (data, func, func_at, func_after) {

            //first I launch some function              
            func.apply(animData, arguments);

            //then I filter an array of objects             
            data.filter(function(e){
                if(e.trigger == 'at' && e.link == animData.id) return true; 
            }).forEach(function(e){

                //And apply the function to all objects that've been filtered
                //These  functions apply at the same time as the first, "func"                  
                func_at.apply(e, arguments);
            });

            //When my "func" and all "func_at" operations are resolved, I have
            //to filter my array again and execute "func_after" function
            data.filter(function(e){
                if(e.trigger == 'auto' && e.link == animData.id)  return true;
            }).forEach(function(e){
                func_after.apply(e, arguments);
            });

        };
```

Thing is, that I have to apply this `buildChain` function to recursive function:

```
function playChain(animData){

            function func() {
                //some action
            }

            function func_at () {
                playChain(this);
            }

            function func_after () {
                playChain(this);
            }

            s.buildChain(data, animData, func, func_at, func_after);
        }
```

I know, that somehow it can be solved with `jQuery.Deffered()` object, but I get stuck when it comes to recursive cycle. Because actual chain can start from an object then there would be few `func_at`, then one `func_after`, then a `func_at` again.

Comment: (1) which functions are asynchronous? (2) do you really mean `arguments` (in three places) or is that pseudocode?

Comment: No, it's not a pseudo code. data is an Object and func, func_at and func_after - some random functions passed as arguments. "func" and "func_at" start simultaneously, "func_after" should start after all  other are done.

Comment: So "func" and "func_at" are asynchronous - they return promises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added return resolved `$.Deferred()` Object to my function.

```
function playChain(animData){

            function func() {
                //some action
                return new $.Deferred().resolve();
            }

            function func_at () {
                playChain(this);
            }

            function func_after () {
                playChain(this);
            }

            s.buildChain(data, animData, func, func_at, func_after);
        }
```

Then I've corrected the buildChain function.

```
this.buildChain = function (data, animData, func, func_at, func_after) {

            function act1 () {

                var d = func.apply(animData, arguments);

                data.filter(function(e){
                    if(e.trigger == 'at' && e.link == animData.id) return true;
                }).forEach(function(e){
                    func_at.apply(e, arguments);
                });
                return d;
            }

            function act2() {
                data.filter(function(e){
                    if(e.trigger == 'auto' && e.link == animData.id)  return true;
                }).forEach(function(e){
                    func_after.apply(e, arguments);
                });
            }

            act1().done(act2);
        };
```

Comment: But that doesn't seem to wait for the `func_at` and `func_after` asynchronous calls?

Comment: The thing is, that func_at calls at the same time as func. And func_after is in act2, that is called only after act1 resolved, so if you put `return new $.Deferred().resolve();` in setTimeout(), it would wait.